# Two different UITableViewCell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to create one TableView that has 2 section rows.
this table has 2 section (first section has 1 cell and second section has 3 cell)

notice:cell of first section different with cells of second section.

this is my code but don't working!!!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *name = [_names objectForKey:key];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"CustomerCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
        FirstCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[FirstCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.nameLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blue"];
        cell.numberLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1212432543"];
        cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"profile.png"];

        return cell;
//this part not working !!! XD

    }
    else if (indexPath.section >= 1) {

        CustomerCell *cell = (CustomerCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomerCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomerCell class]]) {
                    cell = (CustomerCell *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.titleLable.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**customerCell** & **FirstCell** are tow `UITableViewCell` for custom cells.
when I to do run this code only section one not working and don't show cell but another section is working please guide me and tell me where is it my mistake.

Comment: I think problem is here: "            cell = [[FirstCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];" you should load nib like you have done for second section.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora Its not need to load a nib, it can be a custom class for `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @iphonic: He is not using its xib while creating the firstcell. Asper his implementation that was just a guess. As I have not seen the full code.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora Isn't it same as [[UITableViewCell alloc] init] where `UITableViewCell == FirstCell` ?

Comment: @iphonic: Depends on his approach as he has created cell in different way for second section. Let him check once.

Comment: `NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomerCell" owner:nil options:nil];` shouldn't it be **owner:self** instead of nil ?

Comment: guys I so confused!!! FirstCell & customerCell have xib file and I load cell from there!!!

Comment: @mamal10 : Have you resolved your issue or not?

Comment: I cannot resolve my issue.

Comment: @mamal10: try this
  FirstCell *cell = (FirstCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strEvalIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

Comment: please tell me how to use 2 TableViewCell in one tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FirstCell *cell = (FirstCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strEvalIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil)
{
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: again my app crashed on this line :             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:self options:nil];

Comment: @mamal10 Reason of crash please?

Comment: I don't know about reason of crash but print this error in console : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Can you please edit your post and paste required code?

Comment: a few minute wait now put all project

Comment: @mamal10: What was the issue?

Comment: your code is right but my xcode was hanged when I remove FirstCell class and create it again this code working!!! :D

Comment: @mamal10: It happens no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same code as in the second cell.

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
FirstCell *cell = (FirstCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[FirstCell class]]) {
                cell = (FirstCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
// Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blue"];
    cell.numberLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1212432543"];
    cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"profile.png"];

    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Don't answer in hurry. if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomerCell class]] should be  if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[FirstCell class]]

Comment: Made the change. Thanks.

Comment: my app crashed in this line : NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:nil options:nil];

Comment: yes my dude and my app crashed on this line :        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:nil options:nil];

Comment: @mamal10: You are ignoring my statement its owner self? and not nil.

Comment: When you say crash. Mention crash log as well. So that we can help you in it.

Comment: @mamal are you sure your nib file name is FirstCell and also try to change the owner parameter to self.