# UITableViewCell with nib not show after init

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `.xib` associated. I don't know why but after the init the table view remains empty with no cell. If I rotate the iPad the cell magically appears.

In `viewDidLoad` I have registered table view to the `.xib`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VirtualFileTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:VirtualFileTableViewCellReuseID];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake([self.topLayoutGuide length], 0.0f, [self.bottomLaoyout guide length], 0.0f);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake([self.topLayoutGuide length], 0.0f, [self.bottomLaoyout guide length], 0.0f);
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

       self.tableView.alpha = ( self.viewType == ViewTypeList ? 1.0f : 0.0f );

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = VirtualFileTableViewCellReuseID;
    VirtualFileTableViewCell * cell = (VirtualFileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.sizeLabel.text = @"5 KB";

    return cell;
}
```

In other table view in the same project with the exactly same procedure all works fine. Ideas ?

### Edit

I've notice another important detail. The problem is generated by this two line

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake([self.topLayoutGuide length], 0.0f, [self.bottomLaoyout guide length], 0.0f);
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake([self.topLayoutGuide length], 0.0f, [self.bottomLaoyout guide length], 0.0f);
```

in `viewDidAppear`. I've tried to insert in `viewDidLoad` and all works, but the problem is that I can't using `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` because in `viewDidLoad` they haven't the correct value.

Instead if I use default cell without `xib` this two line doesn't generate the problem and all work fine.

Comment: Check if your custom cell nib has same ReuseIdentifier or not.

Comment: Here's the definition `#define VirtualFileTableViewCellReuseID @"VirtualFileTableViewCellReuseID"`

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911351/two-different-uitableviewcell-in-uitableview/22911900#22911900

Comment: see the edit in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create object of custom cell `VirtualFileTableViewCell * virtualFileTableViewCellObj` in your TableView ".h" file and write following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :-

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = VirtualFileTableViewCellReuseID;

    if(virtualFileTableViewCellObj == nil)
        {
            virtualFileTableViewCellObj= (VirtualFileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        }


    virtualFileTableViewCellObj.sizeLabel.text = @"5 KB";

    return virtualFileTableViewCellObj;
}
```

**Update:**

Write the below mentioned lines in `ViewDidAppear`

```
self.tableView.delegate = self; 
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: doesn't work... the cells are showed only if I use normal init without using xib.

Comment: Works ! And the reason is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"albumListCell";
   VirtualFileTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
         cell = (VirtualFileTableViewCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VirtualFileTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

And Change in property of custom cell named "Identifier" eanter value "albumListCell"(withour quete)
Because

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"albumListCell";
```

[image]